# Getting an apache spark dataframe in the right format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to convert some input to the format I want in an spark dataframe. 
The input I have is a Sequence of this case class with up to 10,000,000 classes (or possibly also the Json string before I convert it to the case class..):

```
case class Element(paramName: String, value: Int, time: Int)
```

As a result I want a dataframe like this:

```
|Time | ParamA | ParamB | ParamC | Param 10,000 |  
|1000 | 432432 | 8768768 | Null....... | 75675678622 |  
|2000 | Null.......| Null.........| 734543 | Null................. |
```

....
So not every parameter has to have to be defined for all time slots. Missing values should be filled with Null. And there are probably going to be 10,000 parameter and around 1000 time slots.

The way I do it right now seems to be very bad from the efficiency:

```
case class Elements(name: String, value: Int, time: Int)

case class GroupedObjects(time: Int, params: (String, Int)*)

 //elements contains the seq of Element
val elementsRdd: RDD[Elements] = sc.parallelize(elements)
val groupedRDD: RDD[GroupedObjects] = elementsRdd
  .groupBy(element => element.time)
  .map(tuple => GroupedObjects(tuple._1, tuple._2.map(element =>
    (element.name, element.value)).toSeq: _*))

//transforming back to json string to get right format for RDD
val jsonRDD: RDD[String] = groupedRDD.map { obj =>
  "{\"time\":" + obj.time + obj.params.map(tuple => 
     ",\"" + tuple._1 + "\":" + tuple._2).reduce(_ + _) + "}"
}
val df = sqlContext.read.json(jsonRDD).orderBy("time")
df.show(10)
```

The problem I see here is definitely the change back to a String, only to read it in again in the right format. I would be really glad for any help showing me how to get the input case class in the wanted dataframe format.
With the way I am doing it right now it is really slow and I get a heap size exception for 10,000,000 input lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to build Row objects and define the RDD schema manually, something like the following example:

```
// These extra imports will be required if you don't have them already
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StructField, StructType}

//elements contains the seq of Element
val elementsRdd = sc.parallelize(elements)

val columnNames = elementsRdd.map(_.name).distinct().collect().sorted

val pivoted = elementsRdd.groupBy(_.time).map {
  case (time, elemsByTime) =>
    val valuesByColumnName = elemsByTime.groupBy(_.name).map {
      case (name, elemsByTimeAndName) => (name, elemsByTimeAndName.map(_.value).sum)
    }
    val allValuesForRow = columnNames.map(valuesByColumnName.getOrElse(_, null))
    (time, allValuesForRow)
}

val schema = StructType(StructField("Time", IntegerType) :: columnNames.map(columnName => StructField(columnName, IntegerType, nullable = true)).toList)
val rowRDD = pivoted.map(p => Row.fromSeq(p._1 :: p._2.toList))
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
df.show(10)
```

I tried this locally with 10,000,000 elements like this:

```
val elements = (1 to 10000000).map(i => Element("Param" + (i % 1000).toString, i + 100, i % 10000))
```

And it completes successfully in a reasonable time.

Answer (score 2):

As of Spark 1.6 there's a `pivot` function. It works on DataFrames. Since you are using case classes, this is as easy as:

```
val elementsRdd: RDD[Elements] = sc.parallelize(elements)
val elementsDF = elementsRdd.toDF()
```

You can then do:

```
elementsDF.groupBy($"time").pivot(...)
```

See the documentation for [`GroupedData`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData) for more on `pivot()`, but this should be more than enough for you to go on.

Comment: Hey David, thank you for your reply. I just tried it out in the following way:
 `val dfTransformed = df.groupBy("time").pivot("name").sum("value")`  
The sum is just to get back a dataframe. This works really well for a lot of timestamps and few parameters (time 1 to 1000000 and params 2) but for many parameters and fewer timestamps this does not really work well. My usecase would be 1000 timestamps and 10,000 distinct parameters.  For example for 100 timestamps and 10,000 it takes forever and leads java heap space exception even faster than my first approach. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: For example with my first approach I could do 10,000 parameters with 100 timestamps and got a heap exception when putting it up to 1000 timestamps. With the pivot approach I am getting the heap exception already at 10,000 parameters and 100 timestamps.

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong. Honestly, 1.6 is relatively new -- the other answer building row objects on the fly is the way I am more familiar with. Did you try that way? Since this is new functionality, you are possibly pushing it past what it was designed for. You might want to ask that specific question -- why is `pivot` so much slower than another approach. That being said -- my understanding is that Spark is designed for long, thin data, not short, wide data. It's probably not going to be fun generally to have 1,000,000 columns in Spark.

Comment: What if you do the sum first:`elemDF.groupBy($"time", $"name").agg(sum($"value") as "value").groupBy($"time").pivot("name").sum("value")`